# How to use Eloquent to retrieve certain File Types from a File Table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Considering a Product has Images, Videos and PDF's... on an eCommerce site.

I would like to be able to call an eloquent call based on the type of file it is, for example:

**Images:**

$product->file->images()
Will provide an eloquent collection of images for the product...

**Videos:**

$product->file->videos()
Will provide an eloquent collection of videos for the product...
**PDF:**

$product->file->pdf()
Will provide an eloquent collection of pdf for the product...

[image: Files Table]

So far I only have a **Product.php** (model):

```
    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['file'];

    public function file()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(File::class, 'file_refer_id', 'id');
    }
```

And a **File.php** (model):

```
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'file_refer_id', 'id');
    }
```

Which contains the appropriate relationship between the Product and File.

What is the best way to write a function on the File.php (model) to filter out products based on the file type?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a One to Many relationship between Product and File, lets rename the relationship to files().

This could achieve your results:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(File::class, 'file_refer_id', 'id');
    } 

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->files()->where('type', 1);
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->files()->where('type', 2);
    } 

    public function pdfs()
    {
        return $this->files()->where('type', 3);
    } 
}
```

So you can get $videos, pdfs and images by saying:

```
$product->videos;

$product->pdfs;

$product->images;
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work... I was trying to do this on the File.php (model)